# How to use WebView in a tab and call "(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)"?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview, android-tabhost, android-logcat

I have three tabs that I want to use to utilize my three webviews to display specific  domains. Everything builds find but when I try to launch the app it force closes when I Run it & if I Debug it -- it stays open with a the layout and views (it basically does nothing when debugging.)

logcat says

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.client/com.company.client.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?**

How do I call that?

Heres my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TabHost th;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    th.setup();


    TabSpec firstSpec=th.newTabSpec("Classes & Events");
    firstSpec.setIndicator("Classes & Events", null);
    Intent firstIntent= new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
    firstIntent.putExtra("backswipe", false);
    firstSpec.setContent(firstIntent);
    th.addTab(firstSpec);

    TabSpec secondSpec=th.newTabSpec("Twitter");
    secondSpec.setIndicator("Twitter", null);
    Intent secondIntent= new Intent(this, WebViewActivity2.class);
    secondSpec.setContent(secondIntent);
    th.addTab(secondSpec);

    TabSpec thirdSpec=th.newTabSpec("Facebook");
    thirdSpec.setIndicator("Facebook", null);
    Intent thirdIntent= new Intent(this, WebViewActivity3.class);
    thirdSpec.setContent(thirdIntent);
    th.addTab(thirdSpec);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}

}
```

the WebView code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

public WebView webView_A;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    webView_A = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
    webView_A.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView_A.loadUrl("http://www.eventbrite.com");

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.web_view, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

The XML the main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFB84D" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-3dip"
        android:layout_weight="0" >
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Heres the logcat.

> 05-23 01:23:06.886: W/dalvikvm(14673): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4160e930)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673): **FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.company.client/com.company.client.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void
>   setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?**
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void
>   setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:747)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at com.company.client.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>       05-23 01:23:06.910: E/AndroidRuntime(14673):  ... 11 more

So, how can I get my WebViewActivities acitive in a the tabs and do what logcat tells to me to?

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept behind the Tab-Activity as follows

**TabHost** is a container for a tabbed window view. 
This object holds two children: a set of tab labels that the user clicks to select specific tab, and a FrameLayout object that displays the content of that page.

The individual element are typically controlled using this container object, rather then setting values on the child elements themselves.

**TabWidget** displays a list of tab labels representing each page in the parent's tab collection. The container object for this widget is TabHost. 
When a user selects a tab, this object sends a message to container, TabHost, to tell to switch the display page. The container TabHost is used to add labels, add the callback handler, and manage callbacks.

so adjust your layout as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-3dip"
        android:layout_weight="0" >
    </TabWidget>
  </LinearLayout>

  </TabHost>
```

And code snippet as follows -

```
    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("InstructionId");
                           tabSpec.setIndicator("INSTRUCTIONS",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.manual));
    intent = new Intent(this, InstructionsScreen.class);
    intent.putExtra("backswipe", false);

    tabSpec.setContent(intent);   // set content must required the first before adding the tab
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

Answer (score 0):

First Mistake I noticed is, you are trying to set content after adding Tab:

```
   TabSpec firstSpec=th.newTabSpec("Classes & Events");
   firstSpec.setIndicator("Classes & Events", null);
   Intent firstIntent= new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
   th.addTab(firstSpec);
   firstSpec.setContent(firstIntent);
```

It should be:

```
   TabSpec firstSpec=th.newTabSpec("Classes & Events");
   firstSpec.setIndicator("Classes & Events", null);
   Intent firstIntent= new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
   firstSpec.setContent(firstIntent);
   th.addTab(firstSpec);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do is

```
TabSpec firstSpec=th.newTabSpec("Classes & Events");
firstSpec.setIndicator("Classes & Events", null);
Intent firstIntent= new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
firstSpec.setContent(firstIntent);
th.addTab(firstSpec);



TabSpec secondSpec=th.newTabSpec("Twitter");
secondSpec.setIndicator("Twitter", null);
Intent secondIntent= new Intent(this, WebViewActivity2.class);
secondSpec.setContent(secondIntent);
th.addTab(secondSpec);



TabSpec thirdSpec=th.newTabSpec("Facebook");
thirdSpec.setIndicator("Facebook", null);
Intent thirdIntent= new Intent(this, WebViewActivity3.class);
thirdSpec.setContent(thirdIntent);
th.addTab(thirdSpec);
```

Because you need to set content view before adding tab inside tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

LogCat tells you that you did initialize the tabhost correctly. You should use 'void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'.